# App Engine Modules - Why do I see a message about backends

Tags: google-app-engine

I've started experimenting with the new App Engine Modules feature (using Python).

Everthing seems to be working but I'm seeing the message "Looks like you're using Backends. We suggest that you make the switch to App Engine Modules. See the Modules documentation to learn more about converting" in the App Engine Dashboard.

This is a new app which has never had any backends defined. Is this message erroneous or a sign of mis-configuration? Anyone else seeing a similar message?

Thanks
Richard

Answer (score 0):

Does your application holds a backends.yaml or backends.xml file ?

If so, you were or have been testing/using [Google App Engine backends](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/backends/) which have been deprecated with the 1.9.1 release. Backends being configurable with [modules](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/modules/), there's no longer a need for the backends feature.

Removing the file should get rid of the warning message.